# Create JSON object and convert it to String in Java

Tags: java, string, json, http

I need to send a quite long JSON header through an http post. In Python was like this:

```
    self.body_header = {
                "client": self.client_name,
                "clientRevision": self.client_version,
                "uuid": str(uuid.uuid4()),
                "session": self.get_sessionid()}

    self.body = {
                "header": self.body_header,
                "country": {"IPR":"1021", "ID":"223", "CC1":"0", "CC2":"0", "CC3":"0", "CC4":"2147483648"},
                "privacy": 1}
```

I need to do something similar in Java, ie, create somehow a JSON struct, convert it to a String and send it via http.

The question is, how can I achieve that easily? Any useful libraries? I know how to send it, but not how to build it and then create a String.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

You can create a Java Object (POJO) and serialize it as JSON by doing:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(yourObject);
```

You can then send the string over HTTP.

If you do not want to go the POJO route, you can still create the JSON struct using [JsonElement](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html), [JsonArray](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html), [JsonObject](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) in the Gson API.

Comment: You can also just create a map and serialize that if you don't want to create a POJO.  Secondly, I was using gson in a project and found that jackson's performance in my real world case was much better, but I was using it to go from JSON to java rather than the direction you are going.

Answer (score 1):

I like the original [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)

Comment: Link is not working yet all and no description and implementation provided.

Answer (score 0):

i think STO had a similar discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library