# how to pass a map from bean to JSP and consume in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, dictionary, resourcebundle

In server having properties files for i18n, and using ResourceBundle to load and build into a json string. In Jsp it could be called as

```
<% bean.getMessageByLocale('fr'); %>
```

The  getMessageByLocale would be like:

```
public String getMessageByLocale(Locale locale) {
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18nBundle.langbundle", locale);
    int n = 0;
    String ret = "{";
    Enumeration <String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            if (n>0) {
                ret += ",";
            }
            n++;
            String key = keys.nextElement();
            String value = bundle.getString(key);
            ret += "\""+key+"\":\""+value+"\"";
        }
        ret += "}";
        System.out.println("json: " + ret);

        return ret;
}
```

The return json string would be like:

```
{"key1":"message 1","key2":"message 2","key3":"message 3"}
```

What is the best way to pass a usable map object which could be directly consumed in jsp and the javascript code to lookup by key?

Comment: Use [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) instead of creating the JSON yourself

Comment: thanks Andreas! Build the json with JSONObject or build json self does not make difference. it needs to be accessed through the bean in jsp to use the messages (by key) to build the html. could you share some code snippet?

Comment: JSONObject is neither the source nor the solution to your problem. But if there are specialized objects for handling JSON data you should be using them. They will do all the work for you (especially the escaping).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a json object in jsp and using it with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046331/creating-a-json-object-in-jsp-and-using-it-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Simply return a JSON formatted string from the method, and then load the JSON object into your JavaScript with an AJAX call.

Comment: thank you Mico! the string inside the json is need in the jsp to build the html, can't wait for it to be done in AJAX call.