# How to convert between JavaScript associated array and Java List Map

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, list, dictionary

I have code as below, I want to do all in Java code to create categoryListMap object, then convert to categoryList, how can I do?

```
    ...
    var categoryList = [];

<%
    List<Object> modelMaster = psiSearchForm.getModelMaster();
    String parentKey = "";
    String categoryKey = "";
    String text = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < modelMaster.size(); i++) {
        Map option = (Map) modelMaster.get(i);

        parentKey = (String)option.get(ConstantContainer.MODALITY);
        categoryKey = (String)option.get(ConstantContainer.CATEGORY);
        text = categoryKey + ": " + (String)option.get(ConstantContainer.CATEGORY_NAME);
%>
        categoryList.push({
            parent: "<%=parentKey%>",
            key: "<%=parentKey%><%=categoryKey%>",
            text: "<%=text%>"
        }); 
<%
    }
%>
```

Comment: JSP expressions are not chuck norris it cant call array.push of javascript from Java. Only chuck norris has that power.

Comment: I mean After created List Map in java, then use for loop in javascript  to push to categoryList, may I make sense?

Comment: you can create a JSON object  and assign that to categoryList

Comment: can you show me a sample

Comment: Yes your code is sufficient, I can understand what you are trying to do. But that is impossible. Java cant call javascript in a template. You can instead create a json object and assign that to categoryList

Comment: I am not a java developer. But this will be the closest one that you are looking for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046331/creating-a-json-object-in-jsp-and-using-it-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call JavaScript function in JSP, this is not possible. You can instead create the array in JSP and set the final value in javascript.

```
<body>
<%

    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

        object.put("name", "santa"+i);
        object.put("mail", "santa"+i+"@email.com");

        arr.add(object);
    }

%>
    <script>
        var obj = <%= arr %>;

        console.log("JS obj", obj);
    </script>
</body>
```

The library I am using is json-simple-1.1.1.jar.

page import

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject,org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>
```