# I want to parse JSON objects such that I can show table of JSON entries instead of directly showing JSON objects as an output in jsp

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jsp

here is snap of how my output look like. Can you please let me know how do I make table of these JSON object in jsp.

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBG8Q.png)

Comment: Can you please add the output as part of the post itself?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046331/creating-a-json-object-in-jsp-and-using-it-with-jquery