# Creating JSON data

Tags: java, ajax, json, jsp

I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154845/returning-json-response-from-servlet-to-javascript-jsp-page) as a basis, but I cannot get it to work. My major problem is that the .add() method isn't available in the JSONArray class.

establishmentList is just an ArrayList.

```
    JSONObject json      = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray  addresses = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject address;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        for (Establishment est : establishmentList) {
            address = new JSONObject();
            try {
                address.put("name", est.getBusinessName());
                address.put("address", est.getAddress());
                address.put("rating", est.getRating());
                addresses.add(address); //<-- method not available, compiler error
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        json.put("Addresses", addresses);
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println(json.toString());
    }
```

My imports for the JSON are:

```
      import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONArray;
      import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONException;
      import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
            addresses.put(address);
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the issue is in the JQuery parsing. I'll post a new question.