# How to structure response/requests in java servlet with ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

Im creating a website which has a java servlet running in the background (as service) and a html front-end running ajax as the request/response tool.
I need some input on how to make the request/response structure the right way. Right now Im thinking of having a switch in the java servlet and send action parameters to it. Then send the response back.
But Im not sure how to approach this the right way - How do i send different response back? If its just a update command string, should i send the text itself or just a command number that javascript will turn into a text? I guess objects should be serialized and sent as json? How would i make the right switch structure in the back and front for the requests/responses?

Comment: You can think about JSON that can be passed from your java servlet and accessed in javascript ajax. :) (P.S.: search about the same, there are plenty of options, like: similar not same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154845/returning-json-response-from-servlet-to-javascript-jsp-page#answer-6162267)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `java.util.Map<String, String>` to store the String values as key and value pairs in your Servlet. Like,

```
Map<String, String> json = new HashMap<String, String>();
json.put("fileId", fileId);
json.put("name", fileName);
```

and return the String by converting this Map into String using, `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`.

```
return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(json); // this will return String
```

to retrieve the key value pairs in your Ajax response in success method,

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.fileId);
    console.log(response.fileName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for input - how would you convert into a string with Objectmapper?

Comment: @Mac Luc using ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString() method that can be used to serialize any Java value as a String. Check the updated answer.