# Unable to set data-url with json string

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am using Bootstrap Table Extentions in a asp:

```
<table id="tbl" data-toggle="table" data-height="299" data-url="${data}" data-toolbar="#filter-bar" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-filter="true">
```

I have a json string java object in a Spring @RestFullcontroller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTableData")
public String getTableData() {
    List<Product> products = productDao.getAll();
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Product.class, new   ProductAdapter()).create();
    String p = gson.toJson(products);
    System.out.println(p);
    return p;
}
```

Setting the data-url with ${data} does not work. Any ideas? Can I put /getTableData for the url?

Answer (score 0):

I believe data-url="" attribute suppose url that return data as json, you just trying to put json as string to that attribute.

Two ways:

1) Take a look on your table and try find out something like data attribute, that receive data as array and pass data as you do now

2) Change your servlet/controller code to return json that will be accessible by url, you just need set response content type as "application/json" and write your data to response output. Here is an example [Returning JSON response from Servlet to Javascript/JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154845/returning-json-response-from-servlet-to-javascript-jsp-page)

Comment: How to I make the url request the data?

Comment: Ok, try to put your full url to attribute, data-url="/getTableData", make sure your url return json, put your url in browser and you should see json string

Comment: Still no luck i have localhost:8080/mypath/getTableData

Comment: When I go there there is json